# Int32 to Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell

What function, or series of functions, can convert an Int32 to an Int in Haskell? I know that HashTable.hashString can convert to an Int32, but I need a function that can convert the other way.

Answer (score 17):

```
ghci> import Data.Int
ghci> fromIntegral (5 :: Int32) :: Int
5
ghci> fromIntegral (5 :: Int) :: Int32
5
```

Comment: Welcome to polymorphic return types! These were very mysterious when I first met haskell.

Answer (score 6):

Stop. [Hoogle time](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int32+-%3E+Int)!...Sadly, Hoogle fails to answer the question well this time. Skipping to the answer...

`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`

[(docs at hackage.haskell.org)](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral)

Note the type signature of `fromIntegral` indicates that it will turn any `Integral` into any `Num`. Since `Int32` has a declared instance of `Integral`, and `Int` has a declared instance of `Num`, the `fromIntegral` function will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

`fromIntegral` will convert from Int32 to Int or the other way around.